# Drop Duplicates Based On Column Conditional Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe with the following columns:

- Action ("start", "end")
- points (integer)
- cards (integer)
  and suppose the dataframe looks like this:

```
Action  points  cards
start   1       1
start   2       2
start   2       3
end     1       1
end     2       2
end     2       3
```

I'd like to drop all rows that have duplicate points values, but ONLY when the action is equal to start. Desired output is therefore:

```
Action  points  cards
start   1       1
start   2       2
end     1       1
end     2       2
end     2       3
```

the following commands do not work:

```
df[df["action"] == "start"].drop_duplicates(["points"]) # no effect
df[df["action"] == "start"].drop_duplicates(["points"], inplace=True) # Error
df[df["action"] == "start"] = df[df["action"] == "start"].drop_duplicates(["points"]) # Adds a row of NaNs where there should be nothing
```

Assuming I can't just `dropna()`, what should I do?
Bonus question: suppose I wanted to drop the (start, 2, 2) row instead of the (start, 2, 3) row. How would I do that?

Comment: Is your desired output supposed to be identical to the input or is that an error?

Comment: "keep" arg changes behaviour of drop duplicates method. E.g. "keep"=False will drop all found duplicates. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: That was an error, fixed. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Divide the dataframe into two parts and drop duplicates on the needed part. Concat to get your dataframe. See below.

```
df_start = df[df.action=="start"] \
             .orderby(["points"]) \
             .drop_duplicates(["points"], keep="last")

df_rest = df[df.action!="start"]

df = pd.concat([df_start, df_rest], axis=0)
```